# Checking if 2 geolocations with radius are within eachothers radius

Tags: c#

I'm trying to determine if a tracker is within 5km of it's destination. 
This tracker has a Lat, Lng and Accuracy

So this would give us

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Current location
        var trackerLat = <Lat>; 
        var trackerLng  =  <Lng>;
        var trackerAcc = 150;

        // Destination
        var destinationLat = <Lat>;
        var destinationLng  =  <Lng>;
        var withingRange  = 5000;


        if (isWithingRange(trackerLat, trackerLng, trackerAcc, destinationLat, destinationLng, withingRange))
            Console.WriteLine("Close");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not close");

    }

    private static bool isWithingRange(double c1x, double c1y, double r1, double c2x, double c2y, double r2) {
        var dX = c1x - c2x;
        var dY = c1y - c2y;
        var radius = r1 + r2;

        var distsqt = Math.Sqrt((dX * dX) + (dY * dY));


        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Val1: {0}, val2: {1}", distsqt, radius));

        if (distsqt < radius) 
            return true; 
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

But this says it's always within range :(

I would think the range format is wrong compared to the coordinate system, but I can't seem to find on how to convert it correctly

fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FEGC2B

Comment: Please put some actual examples in, instead of `<Lat>` and `<Lng>`, so we can test any potential solutions

Comment: Note that latitude and longitude aren't in units of kilometers. Trying to compare lat/lng and km is not going to work, ever

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `GeoCoordinate` (System.Device.Location). It has a `GetDistanceTo()` method that gives you the distance in meters to another GeoCoordinate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.Device`:

```
var location1 = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(latitude1, longitude1);
var location2 = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(latitude2, longitude2);

return location1.GetDistanceTo(location2) <= (radius1 + radius2);
```